# Facebook URI scheme to page post

Tags: android, facebook, url-scheme

Since two months ago, I've been opening a post of my public page though the following URI scheme:

> fb://post/pageID_postID

The URI is launched in the usual way:

```
try {
    String uri = "fb://post/pageid_" + bundle.getString("post_id");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);
}catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
    String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/pageid/";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Now it's no longer working and I would like to know if anyone discovered a newer URI scheme for this. I also tried this with no luck:

> fb://post/postID

Comment: You can find some way?

Comment: @JoãoArmando sadly it looks like it's no longer possible